# Remove Timer Permanantly on Click of Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I have a popup which automatically loads when the page is loaded, it has a timer on the close button whose time on it varies depending on how many times the popup was viewed by the user. It also has a print button and the popup can be called back up if you press the key 'g'.

My focus is on the 'Print' button. Currently when I click the 'Print' button it sets the `counter` variable to `0`, the `counter` variable being what controls the value of the timer. However if you were to reload the page the timer would not be `0`, it would be either `5`, `15`, `30`, `45` or `60` seconds depending on how many times you had previously viewed the page. I would like the timer to permanently be `0` after the 'Print' button has been clicked. I know this can probably be achieved by `localStorage` or a cookie but I am not exactly sure how.

Please note the timer does not appear to work in the snippet or the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChippeRock/wt1gb9of/4/) as I believe several of the functions are prevented from working such as `document.write`. However it will work in my browser when I create an HTML file. My code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.charCode === 65 || 103) {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
    }
  });
  
  $(function() {
    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
  });
});

// initialization
var counter = 60;
var timesVisited = 0;
var cookieExpirationDays = 7; // don't expire cookies for a week
// test to see if localstorage/sessionStorage is available (localStorage has no expiration date)

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  counter = 60;
  timesVisited = localStorage.getItem("timesVisited");
  // first time
  if ((timesVisited == 0) || (timesVisited < 1)) {
    timesVisited = 1;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 60;
  }
  // second time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 1) && (timesVisited <= 3)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 45;
  }
  // third time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 4) && (timesVisited <= 8)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 30;
  }
  // fourth time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 9) && (timesVisited <= 13)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 15;
  }
  // fifth time
  else if (timesVisited >= 14) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 5;
  }
}
// No localstorage/sessionStorage. Use cookies 
else {
  timesVisited = getCookie("timesVisited");
  console.log(timesVisited);
  // first time
  if ((timesVisited == "") || (timesVisited < 1)) {
    timesVisited = 1;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 60;
  }
  // second time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 1) && (timesVisited <= 3)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 45;
  }
  // third time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 4) && (timesVisited <= 8)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 30;
  }
  // fourth time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 9) && (timesVisited <= 13)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 15;
  }
  // fifth time
  else if (timesVisited >= 14) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 5;
  }
}
var setMsg = setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  if (counter >= 60 && counter >= 70) {
    $("#close-message").html("1:" + (counter - 60));
  } else if (counter >= 60 && counter < 70) {
    $("#close-message").html("1:0" + (counter - 60));
  } else if (counter >= 10) {
    $("#close-message").html("0:" + counter);
  } else if (counter > 0) {
    $("#close-message").html("0:0" + counter);
  } else {
    $(".close").click(function() {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
    });
    $("#timer").remove();
    clearInterval(setMsg);
  }
}, 1000);
});

        function printDiv()
        {
            var content = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
            var win = window.open();
            win.document.write(content);
            win.print(); // JavaScript Print Function
            win.close(); //It will close window after Print.
        $( ".close" ).click(function() {
          $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden"); 
          $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
        });
        $("#timer").remove();
         clearInterval(setMsg);s
        }
```

```css
.t {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
  -o-transform: scale(0.25);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: visible;
}

#t1_1 {
  left: 256px;
  top: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}

#t2_1 {
  left: 334px;
  top: 87px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t3_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 123px;
}

#t4_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 123px;
  word-spacing: -0.3px;
}

#t5_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 141px;
}

#t6_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 160px;
}

#t7_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 179px;
}

#t8_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 141px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t9_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 160px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ta_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 179px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tb_1 {
  left: 343px;
  top: 242px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tc_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 278px;
}

#td_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 297px;
}

#te_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 315px;
}

#tf_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 334px;
}

#tg_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 278px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#th_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 297px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ti_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 315px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#tj_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 334px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tk_1 {
  left: 286px;
  top: 393px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tl_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 429px;
}

#tm_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 448px;
}

#tn_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 466px;
}

#to_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 485px;
}

#tp_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 429px;
  word-spacing: -0.3px;
}

#tq_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 448px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tr_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 466px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ts_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 485px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#tt_1 {
  left: 326px;
  top: 544px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tu_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 580px;
}

#tv_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 599px;
}

#tw_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 618px;
}

#tx_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 618px;
}

#ty_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 636px;
}

#tz_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 636px;
}

#t10_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 655px;
}

#t11_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 580px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t12_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 599px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t13_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 655px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t14_1 {
  left: 264px;
  top: 716px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t15_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 752px;
}

#t16_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 771px;
}

#t17_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 789px;
}

#t18_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 808px;
}

#t19_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 752px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t1a_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 771px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t1b_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 789px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t1c_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 808px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

.s1_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 85.4px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

.s2_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

.s3_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: SymbolMT_1z5;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.s4_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

div {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 578%;
  width: 117.5%;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.PopUp {
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.PopUp .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.PopUp .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.PopUp .content {
  max-height: 117.5%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pdf1 {
  width: 935px;
  height: 1210px;
  background-color: white;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 0;
  border: none;
}

button {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #2D2D2D;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Print {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.close-message {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 9px;
}

.timer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PopUp" class="overlay">
  <div class="PopUp">
    <div class="timer" id="timer"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/87XaOWA.png">
      <p class="close-message" id="close-message"></p>
    </div>
    <a class="close" href="#">&#10005;</a>
    <div class="content" id="content">
      <div id="p1" class="p1" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 885px; height: 878px;">
        <!-- Begin page background -->
        <div id="pg1Overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
        <div id="pg1" class="pg1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vcY42CW.png" id="pdf1" class="pdf1"></img>
        </div>
        <!-- End page background -->

        <!-- Begin text definitions (Positioned/styled in CSS) -->
        <div id="t1_1" class="t s1_1">Player Selection Criteria Evaluator Cue Card</div>
        <div id="t2_1" class="t s2_1">Skating – speed, quickness, technique</div>
        <div id="t3_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t4_1" class="t s4_1">Forward and Backward</div>
        <div id="t5_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t6_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t7_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t8_1" class="t s4_1">Turn both directions</div>
        <div id="t9_1" class="t s4_1">Stop both directions</div>
        <div id="ta_1" class="t s4_1">Are they in a good position for stability and strength</div>
        <div id="tb_1" class="t s2_1">Passing – technique, control, vision</div>
        <div id="tc_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="td_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="te_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tf_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tg_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and Backhand</div>
        <div id="th_1" class="t s4_1">To moving and stationary target</div>
        <div id="ti_1" class="t s4_1">Vision – do they take a look and select best option</div>
        <div id="tj_1" class="t s4_1">Advanced – board passes, chips, saucer passes</div>
        <div id="tk_1" class="t s2_1">Puck Control – technique, open ice, confined space</div>
        <div id="tl_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tm_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tn_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="to_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tp_1" class="t s4_1">Open carry with speed</div>
        <div id="tq_1" class="t s4_1">Execute dekes and fakes on the 1 on 1</div>
        <div id="tr_1" class="t s4_1">Can they handle the puck in traffic and tight space</div>
        <div id="ts_1" class="t s4_1">Ability to maintain control while being stick checked</div>
        <div id="tt_1" class="t s2_1">Shooting – technique, accuracy, velocity</div>
        <div id="tu_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tv_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tw_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tx_1" class="t s4_1">Velocity</div>
        <div id="ty_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tz_1" class="t s4_1">Accuracy</div>
        <div id="t10_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t11_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and backhand</div>
        <div id="t12_1" class="t s4_1">Wrist shot, snap shot, slap shot</div>
        <div id="t13_1" class="t s4_1">Shot Selection – do they select the best shot for the opportunity?</div>
        <div id="t14_1" class="t s2_1">Game Understanding – Principles of Offence and Defence</div>
        <div id="t15_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t16_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t17_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t18_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t19_1" class="t s4_1">Player understands positional play</div>
        <div id="t1a_1" class="t s4_1">Player supports the puck on the defensive and offensive side of puck</div>
        <div id="t1b_1" class="t s4_1">Player communicates with teammates</div>
        <div id="t1c_1" class="t s4_1">Player has the ability to read and react.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Print" class="Print" align="center">
      <button onclick="printDiv()"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/HcXNoMC.png" /></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edited :** Please test it on your HTML File...
For security reason, the cookie cant running with fiddle.

The cookie cant save number **0**, so i set it to **-1**

You just need update the cookie on setInterval()

```js
var cookieExpirationDays = 7;

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
 return "";
}
function timeEnded(){
 // $(".close").click();
 // $("#timer").remove();
 $("#Print").remove();
}

$(document).ready(function() {

 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.charCode === 65 || 103) {
   $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
   $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
  }
 });

 $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
 $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
 $(".close").click(function() {
  $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
  $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
 });

 var printedCount = parseInt(getCookie("printedCookie"));
 if(printedCount){
  if(printedCount == ""){
   var printedCount = 0;
  }
 }else{
  var printedCount = 0;
 }

 var counter = parseInt(getCookie("lastCounter"));
 if(counter){
  if(counter == ""){
   var counter = 60;
   setCookie("lastCounter", counter, cookieExpirationDays);
  }
 }else{
  var counter = 60;
 }


 var setMsg = setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  setCookie("lastCounter", counter, cookieExpirationDays);
  if (counter >= 60 && counter >= 70) {
   $("#close-message").html("1:" + (counter - 60));
  }else if(counter >= 60 && counter < 70) {
   $("#close-message").html("1:0" + (counter - 60));
  }else if(counter >= 10) {
   $("#close-message").html("0:" + counter);
  }else if(counter > 0) {
   $("#close-message").html("0:0" + counter);
  }else if(counter <= 0) {

   setCookie("lastCounter", "-1", cookieExpirationDays);
   $("#printed-message1").html("Print Button Removed");

   clearInterval(setMsg);
   timeEnded();
   $("#close-message").html("0:00");
  }
 }, 1000);


 $("#Print button").click(function(){
  printedCount = getCookie("printedCookie");
  printedCount++;
  if(printedCount != ""){
   setCookie("printedCookie", printedCount, cookieExpirationDays);
  }else{
   setCookie("printedCookie", "1", cookieExpirationDays);
  }

  setCookie("lastCounter", "-1", cookieExpirationDays);

  var content = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
  var win = window.open();
  win.document.write(content);
  win.print();
  win.close();

  clearInterval(setMsg);
  timeEnded();
  $("#close-message").html("0:00");
 });




 $("#resetCounter").click(function(){
  setCookie("lastCounter", "0", cookieExpirationDays);
 });

 $("#printed-message").html("Printed Times : " + printedCount);
});
```

```css
.t {
 -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
 -moz-transform-origin: top left;
 -o-transform-origin: top left;
 -ms-transform-origin: top left;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
 -o-transform: scale(0.25);
 -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 white-space: pre;
 overflow: visible;
}

#t1_1 {
 left: 256px;
 top: 35px;
 letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}

#t2_1 {
 left: 334px;
 top: 87px;
 word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t3_1 {
 left: 210px;
 top: 123px;
}

#t4_1 {
 left: 238px;
 top: 123px;
 word-spacing: -0.3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="PopUp" class="overlay">
 <div class="PopUp">
  <div class="timer" id="timer"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/87XaOWA.png">
   <p class="close-message" id="close-message"></p>
   <a href="" id="resetCounter">Click me to reset the counter</a>
   <p class="close-message" id="printed-message">Printed Times : </p>
   <p class="close-message" id="printed-message1"></p>
  </div>
  <a class="close" href="#">&#10005;</a>

  <!-- There is no id="content" -->
  <!-- There is no id="content" -->
  <!-- There is no id="content" -->
  <!-- There is no id="content" -->
  <!-- There is no id="content" -->
  <div class="content" id="content">
   <div id="p1" class="p1" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 885px; height: 878px;">

    <div id="pg1Overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-user-select: none;"></div>

    <div id="pg1" class="pg1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vcY42CW.png" id="pdf1" class="pdf1">
    </div>

    <div id="t1_1" class="t s1_1">Player Selection Criteria Evaluator Cue Card</div>
    <div id="t2_1" class="t s2_1">Skating – speed, quickness, technique</div>
    <div id="t3_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="t4_1" class="t s4_1">Forward and Backward</div>
    <div id="t5_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="t6_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="t7_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="t8_1" class="t s4_1">Turn both directions</div>
    <div id="t9_1" class="t s4_1">Stop both directions</div>
    <div id="ta_1" class="t s4_1">Are they in a good position for stability and strength</div>
    <div id="tb_1" class="t s2_1">Passing – technique, control, vision</div>
    <div id="tc_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="td_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="te_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="tf_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="tg_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and Backhand</div>
    <div id="th_1" class="t s4_1">To moving and stationary target</div>
    <div id="ti_1" class="t s4_1">Vision – do they take a look and select best option</div>
    <div id="tj_1" class="t s4_1">Advanced – board passes, chips, saucer passes</div>
    <div id="tk_1" class="t s2_1">Puck Control – technique, open ice, confined space</div>
    <div id="tl_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="tm_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="tn_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="to_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="tp_1" class="t s4_1">Open carry with speed</div>
    <div id="tq_1" class="t s4_1">Execute dekes and fakes on the 1 on 1</div>
    <div id="tr_1" class="t s4_1">Can they handle the puck in traffic and tight space</div>
    <div id="ts_1" class="t s4_1">Ability to maintain control while being stick checked</div>
    <div id="tt_1" class="t s2_1">Shooting – technique, accuracy, velocity</div>
    <div id="tu_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="tv_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="tw_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="tx_1" class="t s4_1">Velocity</div>
    <div id="ty_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="tz_1" class="t s4_1">Accuracy</div>
    <div id="t10_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="t11_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and backhand</div>
    <div id="t12_1" class="t s4_1">Wrist shot, snap shot, slap shot</div>
    <div id="t13_1" class="t s4_1">Shot Selection – do they select the best shot for the opportunity?</div>
    <div id="t14_1" class="t s2_1">Game Understanding – Principles of Offence and Defence</div>
    <div id="t15_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="t16_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="t17_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="t18_1" class="t s3_1">?</div>
    <div id="t19_1" class="t s4_1">Player understands positional play</div>
    <div id="t1a_1" class="t s4_1">Player supports the puck on the defensive and offensive side of puck</div>
    <div id="t1b_1" class="t s4_1">Player communicates with teammates</div>
    <div id="t1c_1" class="t s4_1">Player has the ability to read and react.</div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Print" class="Print" align="center">
   <button><img src="http://i.imgur.com/HcXNoMC.png" /></button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question. What I am trying to do is this: Once the 'Print' button has been clicked the `counter` variable permanently remains at `0`. BTW for your information I already have the `$(".close").click();` piece of code in my `printDiv()` function. Also, edited post and fiddle so that there is an `id="content"`. As I said, if you want the code to work copy it into an HTML file.

Comment: Edited... you need to set two cookie ( LastCount & PrintedCount ).